# Are there hobbyist microscopes which can take digital pictures of cells?

Tags: microscopy

I'm reading a biology textbook and it's suggesting things like taking onion skin etc. and looking at it under a microscope to see its cells.  I'm tempted to do this for fun, and maybe share photos of what I find on Facebook.  (I remember using a microscope in school, but all I ended up seeing was air bubbles.)  I'm wondering if there is some way of doing this as a hobbyist (on a budget of, say, $100).

I saw [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CGP9BFQ) on Amazon:

> [image: TOMLOV DM101 Digital USB Microscope Camera 500X]

but I'm not sure if it can see individual cells.  It doesn't look like it can do that.

**Question**: Are there hobbyist microscopes which can take digital pictures of cells?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure about the price. Look for something with 400x magnification or more, and to see cells get a slide microscope with lower illumination. Some come with pre-prepared slides that are stained to give contrast. Many without built-in cameras are compatible with separately-sold cameras.

Comment: “Hobbyist” seems poorly defined here. Is that just the cost of under 100$, or are there other requirements?

Comment: It implies I'm not particularly knowledgeable about what features I should search for.  I'm probably only going to use it a handful of times (for fun), so it shouldn't be expensive.  I don't have additional equipment.  And I'll probably ask random people on the Internet for suggestions of cool things to take photos of.

Comment: Search for "usb digital microscope". These are quite cheap (generally under 100$) with up to 1000x magnification, they are eay to use, and they connect to your computer for taking images. Obviously, the image quality is way worse than using a professional tabletop microscope, but I consider them useful enough for a hobbyist.

Comment: @Domen this is a cool suggestion that could readily be an answer, IMO.